# Controlling the allocation bias in small RCT

Tags: r, bias, clinical-trials, random-allocation

In order to contain the `allocation bias`, I would like to understand if it is possible to have a randomization process during the patients enrollement controlling for certain variables in a very small RCT. Let's suppose that my RCT has the following *PICO* questions:

- **P**: *Subjects with known history of hypertension (>3 Yrs)*
- **I**: *New HTN drug*
- **C**: *Standard HTN drug*
- **O**: *Does the treatment with "new HTN drug" improved the survival at the end of the trial?*

My problem here is the sample size. I need to have comparable groups, thus I would like to know if I can allocate subjects during the enrollement based on 4 a-priori selected baseline characteristics:

1. Gender
2. BMI
3. Age
4. Smoking

Is there any `R package` that helps to allocate patients during the enrollement in order to have comparable groups (for the a-priori selected characteristics) at the end of the trial ?

Comment: Look into [minimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimisation_(clinical_trials)). From a quick look, the R-package [`Minirand`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Minirand/) implements minimization algorithms.